# How can I animate a change to a background image?

Tags: android, animation

I am creating a new activity that blurs the underlying activity.  I created this by doing the following:

- In the old activity, take a screenshot and send it as a bytearray in the Intent
- In the new activity, give it a transparent theme
- Have the new activity fetch the image from the Intent, then set it to the background.
- Have a layer above that that blurs the background.

However, I would like to fade in the background change instead of it being instant.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("image")) {
    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    if (byteArray != null) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);

        if (drawable != null) {
            mBackgroundFrame.setBackground(drawable);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I animate the setBackground(drawable) with a fade in?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `mBackgroundFrame` is an `ImageView`, you can do a fade in transition as follows:

```
mBackgroundFrame.setBackground(drawable);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
mBackgroundFrame.startAnimation(animation);
```

And create an `anim/fadein.xml` resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `overridePendingTransition`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewlyStartedActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="500" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
           android:fillAfter="true"
           android:duration="500" />
```

this will fade out the current Activity and fade in the new Activity.